# * for strings in Java

Tags: java

In Python, there is a `*` operator for strings, I'm not sure what it's called but it does this:

```
>>> "h" * 9
"hhhhhhhhh"
```

Is there an operator in Java like Python's `*`?

Comment: There is no such operator in Java.

Answer (score 9):

Many libraries have such utility methods.

E.g. [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
String s = Strings.repeat("*",9);
```

or [Apache Commons / Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/):

```
String s = StringUtils.repeat("*", 9);
```

Both of these classes also have methods to pad a String's beginning or end to a certain length with a specified character.

Answer (score 5):

I think the easiest way to do this in java is with a loop:

```
String string = "";
for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
{
    string+="h";
}
```

Comment: Note that if you're going to do a LOT of concatenations, you should use a StringBuilder for performance. (Corollary: If it finishes in a blink of an eye, no optimization needed.)

Comment: String+=String in a loop is pure evil

Comment: See [Effective Java by Josh Bloch](http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Java-2nd-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683), Item 51: Beware the performance of string concatenation

Answer (score 3):

you can use something like this :

```
String str = "abc";
String repeated = StringUtils.repeat(str, 3);

repeated.equals("abcabcabc");
```

Comment: Might want to add a note about where `StringUtils` comes from.

Comment: you r right , you should Use apache libraries (common-lang) .

Answer (score 2):

There is no such operator in Java, but you can use [Arrays.fill()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28char%5B%5D,%20char%29) or Apache Commons [StringUtils.repeat()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#repeat%28char,%20int%29) to achieve that result:

Assuming

```
    char src = 'x';
    String out;
```

with ***Arrays.fill()***

```
    char[] arr = new char[10] ;
    Arrays.fill(arr,src);        
    out = new String(arr);
```

with ***StringUtils.repeat()***

```
    out = StringUtils.repeat(src, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

- seems to be a repeat operator

Use apache libraries (common-lang) : Stringutils.repeat(str, nb)

Answer (score 1):

String.repeat(count) has been available since JDK 11.  [String.repeat(count)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int))

Answer (score 0):

There is no operator like that, but you could assign the sting "h" to a variable and use a for loop to print the variable a desired amount of times.